# Can I find jdk version of jsp project(Build using apache ant) using Can i find jdk version of a project using serialVersionUID number?

Tags: java, jsp, ant, java-6

How can I find the version of jdk used for a jsp project using `serialVersionUID` number inside of a class file?

```js
package com.bsh.kimclient.configuration;

import java.io.PrintStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;

public  class ServiceInitServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3256726165010986496;

    public ServiceInitServlet ()
    public void init()
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The `serialVersionUID` value of an arbitrary project class has nothing whatsoever to do with the JDK version.

Answer (score 1):

Java runtime associates each serializable class with a version number which is serialVersionUID. So it's not possible to retrieve JDK version from UID. However you can get Java version from Java system properties like

```
String version = System.getProperty("java.version");
```